# I need to sum up the Amount value, but only when the PayType="NetPay". Additionally, it needs to be summed for the entire XML

Tags: xml, xslt

These are the first three lines of the needed output: (There are additional columns).

Description                     Amount      Facility    Account

PR 0108 - 0121 (PD 01/27/2023)  47662.17    500         500-1013-00
PR 0108 - 0121 (PD 01/27/2023)  0           500         500-2051-00
PR 0108 - 0121 (PD 01/27/2023)  0           500         500-2054-00

(I can't get it aligned correctly; each PR should fall under Description.)

It is only line one I am concerned with; the rest of the output is working great.

Here are 2 nodes of the XML

```
<Export>
<Record>
    <AccountNo>10</AccountNo>
    <Onsite>87</Onsite>
    <Amount>350001.60</Amount>
    <PayDate>02/03/2023</PayDate>
    <PPStartDate>01/15/2023</PPStartDate>
    <PPEndDate>01/28/2023</PPEndDate>
    <PayRunHours>2080.0000000000</PayRunHours>
    <Description><![CDATA[Severance]]></Description>
    <Desc><![CDATA[Severance]]></Desc>
    <EmpNumber>0000005</EmpNumber>
    <EmpFirstName><![CDATA[Lucy]]></EmpFirstName>
    <EmpLastName><![CDATA[Stinger]]></EmpLastName>
    <OnSiteName><![CDATA[Saber Support - Finance]]></OnSiteName>
    <SiteCode><![CDATA[300 SABER PAYROLL]]></SiteCode>
    <LedgerCode><![CDATA[03]]></LedgerCode>
</Record>
<Record>
    <AccountNo>1013-00</AccountNo>
    <Onsite></Onsite>
    <Amount>-253751.16</Amount>
    <PayDate>02/03/2023</PayDate>
    <PPStartDate>01/15/2023</PPStartDate>
    <PPEndDate>01/28/2023</PPEndDate>
    <PayRunHours></PayRunHours>
    <Description><![CDATA[Net Pay]]></Description>
    <Desc><![CDATA[Net Pay]]></Desc>
    <EmpNumber>0000005</EmpNumber>
    <EmpFirstName><![CDATA[Lucy]]></EmpFirstName>
    <EmpLastName><![CDATA[Stinger]]></EmpLastName>
    <OnSiteName><![CDATA[Saber Support - Finance]]></OnSiteName>
    <SiteCode><![CDATA[300 SABER PAYROLL]]></SiteCode>
    <LedgerCode><![CDATA[]]></LedgerCode>
</Record>
```

Here is the xslt that is working for the majority of the output:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
            xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
            xmlns:vb="urn:the-xml-files:xslt-vb">

<msxsl:script language="VBScript" implements-prefix="vb">
    <![CDATA[

    Function AcctNo(ByVal anIn As String) As String
        Dim anOut as String
        Dim aLen as integer
        
        aLen = Len(anIn)

        if aLen = 11 then
            anOut = anIn
        else
            if aLen = 12 then
                anOut = Replace(anIn, "--", "-")
            elseif aLen = 8 and Left(anIn,1) = "-" then
                    anOut = Mid(anIn, 2)
            elseif aLen = 9 and Left(anIn,2) = "--" then
                    anOut = Mid(anIn, 3)
            else
                anOut = anIn
            end if
        end if

        AcctNo = anOut
            
    End Function
    
 ]]>
</msxsl:script>

<!--This sets the output as text and creates a key to group by -->
<xsl:output method="text" indent="no" />
<xsl:key name="RollupFile" match="Export/Record" use="AccountNo"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    
    <!-- Create a variable to do the summing (rollup) -->
    <xsl:variable name="Rollup">
        <xsl:element name="Export">
            <xsl:for-each select="Export/Record[Amount!= 0]">
                <xsl:element name="Record">
                    
                    <!-- Create variable for formatting the pay period range -->
                    <xsl:variable name="PayStr">
                        <xsl:value-of select="'PR '"/>
                        <xsl:value-of select="substring(PPStartDate,1,2)"/>
                        <xsl:value-of select="substring(PPStartDate,4,2)"/>
                        <xsl:value-of select="' - '"/>
                        <xsl:value-of select="substring(PPEndDate,1,2)"/>
                        <xsl:value-of select="substring(PPEndDate,4,2)"/>
                        <xsl:value-of select="' (PD '"/>
                        <xsl:value-of select="PayDate"/>
                        <xsl:value-of select="')'"/>
                    </xsl:variable>
                    
                    <!-- Create variable for the account number -->
                    <xsl:variable name="ANo">
                        <xsl:value-of select="vb:AcctNo(concat(substring(SiteCode,1,3),'-',Onsite,LedgerCode,'-',AccountNo))"/>
                    </xsl:variable>
                    
                    <TransType>
                        <xsl:value-of select="'6'"/>
                    </TransType>
                    <Date>
                        <xsl:value-of select="PayDate"/>
                    </Date>
                    <CBID>
                        <xsl:value-of select="substring(SiteCode,5)"/>
                    </CBID>
                    <Paid>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$PayStr"/>
                    </Paid>
                    <Desc>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$PayStr"/>
                    </Desc>
                    <Amount>
                        <xsl:value-of select="''"/>
                    </Amount>
                    <Facility>
                        <xsl:value-of select="substring(SiteCode,1,3)"/>
                    </Facility>
                    <AccountNo>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$ANo"/>
                    </AccountNo>
                    <AcctDesc>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$PayStr"/>
                    </AcctDesc>
                    <DR>
                        <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test="Amount &gt; 0">
                                <xsl:value-of select="Amount"/>
                            </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:otherwise>
                                <xsl:value-of select="0"/>
                            </xsl:otherwise>
                        </xsl:choose>
                    </DR>
                    <CR>
                        <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test="Amount &lt; 0">
                                <xsl:value-of select="Amount"/>
                            </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:otherwise>
                                <xsl:value-of select="0"/>
                            </xsl:otherwise>
                        </xsl:choose>
                    </CR>
                    <LineDesc>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$PayStr"/>
                    </LineDesc>
                    <Hours>
                        <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test="PayRunHours &gt; 0">
                                <xsl:value-of select="PayRunHours"/>
                            </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:otherwise>
                                <xsl:value-of select="0"/>
                            </xsl:otherwise>
                        </xsl:choose>
                    </Hours>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:variable>
    
    <!--The output-->
    <xsl:text>Transaction Type,Date,Checkbook ID,Paid To,Description,Amount,Facility,Account,Account Description,Debit,Credit,Line Description,Hours</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>&#x0D;&#x0A;</xsl:text>

    <xsl:for-each select="msxsl:node-set($Rollup)/Export/Record[count(.|key('RollupFile',AccountNo)[1])=1]">
        <xsl:sort select="AccountNo"/>

        <xsl:value-of select="TransType"/>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="Date"/>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="CBID"/>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="Paid"/>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="Desc"/>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="Amount"/>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="Facility"/>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="AccountNo"/>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="AcctDesc"/>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:if test="DR!=0">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('&quot;',format-number(sum(key('RollupFile', AccountNo)/DR),'##,###,###.00'),'&quot;') "/>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:if test="CR!=0">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('&quot;',format-number(sum(key('RollupFile', AccountNo)/CR)*-1,'##,###,###.00'),'&quot;') "/>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="LineDesc"/>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:if test="sum(key('RollupFile', AccountNo)/Hours) &gt; 0">
            <xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(key('RollupFile', AccountNo)/Hours),'#.00') "/>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:text>&#x0D;&#x0A;</xsl:text>      
    </xsl:for-each>

</xsl:template>
```

</xsl:stylesheet>

So basically what I need is one row that totals the Amount for the whole file - but only when the value in the Desc field is NetPay.  Also, it has to be the first output row.

The PayDate is the same for all the rows so I thought I would group and sum by that but I can't seem to get it to work.

Any help anyone could provide would be greatly appreciated.

Regards, Greg

Comment: Please  reduce the code to the minimum required to demonstrate the problem - see: [mcve].

Comment: First you say PayType, then you say Desc. Very confusing!

Answer (score -1):

To sum the `Amount` of all `Record`s in the input XML whose `Desc` is `"Net Pay"`, you can use the following expression:

```
sum(/Export/Record[Desc='Net Pay']/Amount)
```

Comment: Great, where would I put this in my xslt?  It needs to be the first row of the output.

Comment: You can put this where you need this. The expression starts with `/` so it will work from any context. --- **Correction:** it will NOT work from the context of another document, such as from a node set created by a `node-set()` extension function. It would probably be best to define a variable using this expression while you're still in the context of `<xsl:template match="/">`. Then output the value of the variable where you need it.