# How can I create a Grand Total Summary AFTER the Muenchian Grouping/Summing is finished

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, muenchian-grouping

I have been trying, to no avail, to figure out how to do a Grand Total of grouped and summed values using Muenchian Grouping.

Here is my grouping key:

`<xsl:key name="kRcdGroup" match="Export/Record" use="concat(generate-id(..), AccountNo, Description, vb:GetOverrideCode(DeptOverride,LedgerCode))"/>`

The vb function just returns one or the other of the two values passed to it.

I created this variable as a summing medium:

```
<xsl:variable name="vkeyGroup" select="key('kRcdGroup', concat(generate-id(..), AccountNo, Description, vb:GetOverrideCode(DeptOverride,LedgerCode))) "/>
```

This is a pipe delimited text output and I am doing the summing in a for-each loop:

```
<xsl:for-each select="Export/Record[generate-id() = generate-id(key('kRcdGroup',concat(generate-id(..), AccountNo, Description, vb:GetOverrideCode(DeptOverride,LedgerCode)))[1])] ">
```

The output is working just fine up to this point.  However, the client requires a footer to be added.  They want the summary of all those grouped/summed values.

This output is used to upload data to a database, so it has to be in this ridiculous format.  01 is the header, 02 is the detail output and 99 is the footer.  (NOTE:  There should not be a blank line after the header or before the footer, I just had to do that to make in more readable.)

```
01|CA|PAYR 2082027||
 
02|1|1|||23|0736|0704010000|0736131554|PAYR||||0|0704010000||||V0|13864.08|CAD||||CAN Flex CASH_0001|||CP|||||CAN Flex CASH||40|0736|0736131554|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
02|1|2|||23|0736|0701000000|0736131554|PAYR||||0|0701000000||||V0|149480.33|CAD||||CAN Bonus_0002|||CP|||||CAN Bonus||40|0736|0736131554|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
02|1|3|||23|0736|0700793000|0736131554|PAYR||||0|0700793000||||V0|74941.42|CAD||||CAN TXB RRSP_0003|||CP|||||CAN TXB RRSP||40|0736|0736131554|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||

99|238285.83
```

So here is a couple of nodes of the xml:

```
<Export>
    <Record>
        <AccountNo><![CDATA[0700103000]]></AccountNo>
        <Onsite></Onsite>
        <Amount>      47916.63</Amount>
        <PayDate>15062023</PayDate>
        <PayDateCA>06152023</PayDateCA>
        <PPStartDate>20230601</PPStartDate>
        <PPEndDate>06/15/2023</PPEndDate>
        <PPEndDateCA>20230615</PPEndDateCA>
        <Description><![CDATA[CAN Regular                                   ]]></Description>
        <Category>Earning</Category>
        <Desc><![CDATA[CAN Regular]]></Desc>
        <EmpNumber>6001237</EmpNumber>
        <EmpFirstName><![CDATA[Elia]]></EmpFirstName>
        <EmpLastName><![CDATA[DiLoreto]]></EmpLastName>
        <DeptName>0736131554</DeptName>
        <DeptLedgerCode></DeptLedgerCode>
        <OnSiteName><![CDATA[0736131554 - Toronto Office - 0736]]></OnSiteName>
        <SiteCode><![CDATA[]]></SiteCode>
        <DeptOverride></DeptOverride>
        <LedgerCode><![CDATA[0736131554]]></LedgerCode>
        <Constant1>ERN</Constant1>
        <Constant2></Constant2>
        <Constant3></Constant3>
        <Constant4></Constant4>
        <Constant5></Constant5>
        <Filler1><![CDATA[                         ]]></Filler1>
        <Filler2><![CDATA[                  ]]></Filler2>
        <LegalEntity>Deutsche Bank AG CA</LegalEntity>
        <EmpType>FT</EmpType>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <AccountNo><![CDATA[0700793000]]></AccountNo>
        <Onsite></Onsite>
        <Amount>       8833.12</Amount>
        <PayDate>15062023</PayDate>
        <PayDateCA>06152023</PayDateCA>
        <PPStartDate>20230601</PPStartDate>
        <PPEndDate>06/15/2023</PPEndDate>
        <PPEndDateCA>20230615</PPEndDateCA>
        <Description><![CDATA[CAN TXB RRSP                                  ]]></Description>
        <Category>Earning</Category>
        <Desc><![CDATA[CAN TXB RRSP]]></Desc>
        <EmpNumber>6001237</EmpNumber>
        <EmpFirstName><![CDATA[Elia]]></EmpFirstName>
        <EmpLastName><![CDATA[DiLoreto]]></EmpLastName>
        <DeptName>0736131554</DeptName>
        <DeptLedgerCode></DeptLedgerCode>
        <OnSiteName><![CDATA[0736131554 - Toronto Office - 0736]]></OnSiteName>
        <SiteCode><![CDATA[]]></SiteCode>
        <DeptOverride></DeptOverride>
        <LedgerCode><![CDATA[0736131554]]></LedgerCode>
        <Constant1>MEM</Constant1>
        <Constant2></Constant2>
        <Constant3></Constant3>
        <Constant4></Constant4>
        <Constant5></Constant5>
        <Filler1><![CDATA[                         ]]></Filler1>
        <Filler2><![CDATA[                  ]]></Filler2>
        <LegalEntity>Deutsche Bank AG CA</LegalEntity>
        <EmpType>FT</EmpType>
    </Record>
</Export>
```

The Amount value in the for-each loop have their absolute values summed up with a neg (40) or pos (50) flag indicating the sign.

```
<xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="sum($vkeyGroup/Amount) > 0">
                <xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum($vkeyGroup/Amount),'#.00')"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum($vkeyGroup/Amount)*-1,'#.00')"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
```

I have tried creating a second Key to sum up the currency values by the pay date which is the same on every record but because the currency value may be positive or negative it sums differently when grouping by pay date.  I need to be able to summarize the absolute value of the Amount field so that it matches the total of the values in the for-each loop.

I reached out to Jeni Tennison but have not heard back yet - I'm under the gun to get this taken care of.  Any help/examples would be greatly appreciated.  I'm learning through all your help but I still have a long way to go.  Next, I need to understand how to use templates:).

Many thanks, Greg

Comment: Please reduce the example to the minimum required to demonstrate the problem. The part with the absolute values is especially unclear.

Comment: I now see that this is the third time you posted this question: you have https://stackoverflow.com/q/77526389/3016153, and https://stackoverflow.com/q/77018434/3016153. If the answers given to you there did not help you, then I don't see why yet another answer should.

Comment: That when I came up with the second Key to do totaling based on PayDate which is the same for all rows.  But the summed up value does not match the sum of the values in the loop.  I'm not good in xslt-speak so let me describe it in english.  Lets say the xml file has 1000 entries (nodes I guess).  When run through the muenchian method grouping it give me 250 rows - with each row have the amount field summed up by the group.  Now, I need to sum up those 250 rows to get 1 grand total of the Amount field.  Hope this clarifies.  Greg

Comment: "*I need to sum up those 250 rows "* No. You need to sum the 1000 entries.

Comment: Let me give you an example:  Two values in the same group, -50 and 25.  They are summed to get -25 and then because it is a negative value it is multiplied by -1 (in other words, making it an absolute value).  However, when I sum using the pay date as the group (same pay date for all entries, this is a pay register), the sign test is done before the summing so the values get summed to 75 instead of 25.   Therefore, I need to figure out a way to summarize the values in the muenchian group.   What about aggregation or running totals, is that available in xslt 1.0?  Greg

Comment: Additionally, I see you have done this in xslt 2.0 using for-each-group and summing a value in the current-group.  Is there no way to emulate this in version 1.0?

Comment: I don't understand your explanation. Please edit your question and provide a clear and simple way to reproduce the problem, removing everything that has nothing to do with the problem (like that unreadable output you need at the end) and make sure to include enough values - both positive and negative - to demonstrate all possible scenarios, along with their expected outputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am still struggling to understand what is the logic that needs to be applied here.

Maybe this **simplified** example can help:

**XML**

```
<entries>
    <entry>
        <group>A</group>
        <amount>-50</amount>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <group>A</group>
        <amount>25</amount>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <group>B</group>
        <amount>80</amount>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <group>B</group>
        <amount>-20</amount>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <group>C</group>
        <amount>15</amount>
    </entry>
</entries>
```

**XSLT 1.0 + EXSLT node-set() extension function**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="entry-by-group" match="entry" use="group" />

<xsl:template match="/entries">
    <!-- first pass -->
    <xsl:variable name="subtotals">
        <xsl:for-each select="entry[count(. | key('entry-by-group', group)[1]) = 1]">
            <subtotal group="{group}">
                <xsl:variable name="subtotal" select="sum(key('entry-by-group', group)/amount)"/>
                <!-- output absolute value -->
                <xsl:value-of select="translate($subtotal, '-', '')"/>
            </subtotal>
        </xsl:for-each> 
    </xsl:variable>
    <!-- final output -->
    <output>
        <xsl:copy-of select="$subtotals"/>
        <total>
            <xsl:value-of select="sum(exsl:node-set($subtotals)/subtotal)"/>
        </total>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>
  <subtotal group="A">25</subtotal>
  <subtotal group="B">60</subtotal>
  <subtotal group="C">15</subtotal>
  <total>100</total>
</output>
```

This seems to follow the process you describe, although I fail to see how this could be useful.

---

**Note**: If you are using a Microsoft processor, you may have to change this:

```
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
```

to:

```
xmlns:exsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
```

(Or, more conventionaly, declare `xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"` and change all `exsl` prefixes to `msxsl`.)

Comment: Thanks Michael.  If I summed up the absolute values in the xml, it would be 190.  But by summing the summed up by group you get 100.  That is what is needed; again thank you very much.  Of course, I am not doing XML output but rather Text so I will have to figure out how to work that in.  Finally, I can't use exsl so I know about using msxsl.  Thanks again.

Comment: Don't know if you will ever read this, but I figured out how to combine my text output with your sample xml solution by calling a template by name.  Took me quite a while to figure out how to do that (you certainly could have sped things up in that regard) but nonetheless it is now working.  Thanks for the help.